# Could not find a part of the path while trying to retrieve a path in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, directory, filepath

I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;

public partial class view4 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

        string strheadlinesid = string.Empty;

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(
                 Request.QueryString["folder"].ToString())))
            {
                strheadlinesid = Request.QueryString["folder"].ToString();
            }
       }

       Response.Write("<table style='width: 10px; height: 10px; margin-left: 
           100px; margin-top: 10px'>");

        DirectoryInfo Dir = new DirectoryInfo(strheadlinesid);

        FileInfo[] FileList = Dir.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach (FileInfo FI in FileList)
        {

            Response.Write("<tr>");

            Response.Write("<td><a href= view3.aspx?file=" + FI.Name + "> " + 
                FI.Name + "</a></td>");
            Response.Write("</tr>");
        }

        Response.Write("</table>");

    }

    private object DirectoryInfo(string p)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


}
```

I'm getting the path of a directory by storing it in folder. However, when I use it to print the files from that directory, I'm getting the following error:

> Could not find a part of the path
>   'C:\Users\naresh\Documents\Visual\'.

The actual path `C:\Users\naresh\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\C_Manager\Account`. But, the account part is changing dynamically.

Comment: Are you sure you are storing the path correctly?

Comment: Yes Because I'm printing it on the website and It is printing write only.

Comment: Response.Write("<td><a href= view4.aspx?folder=" + directory.FullName + "> " + directory.FullName + "</a></td>");  with this I'm printing the path  and storing in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, your issue is related to security permissions. The typical user account (network service or asp.Net user account) under which your web app runs does have very limited permissions (which is a path under user profile folder). Try modifying permissions for the said folder or running your wep app under different identity (either using IIS settings or ASP.NET impersonation)

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile... dunno if this has already been resolved...

I'd wonder that the path cited by the error message is different from the path you say that you're trying to load/access:

- Path: C:\Users\naresh\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\C_Manager\Account
- Error: C:\Users\naresh\Documents\Visual\

Cutting off at the whitespace after "Visual"?

One thing to check (disclaimer: no idea is this is the problem) is that the path name is URL-encoded when embedded in your link.  E.g., change:

```
Response.Write("<td><a href= view4.aspx?folder="
    + directory.FullName + "> "
    + directory.FullName + "</a></td>");
```

to

```
Response.Write("<td><a href= view4.aspx?folder="
    + Server.UrlEncode(directory.FullName) + "> "
    + directory.FullName + "</a></td>");
```

and see if that makes any difference.

And, of course, any code that's attempting to use this path to access/load/write/etc anything...

Answer (score 0):

Add Your user to your application pool identity and it'll work 
it is all about permissions